# What is the shorthand for Response.Write in asp forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Currently if I have this:

```
<div>
    some dynamic data
</div>
```

I am using

```
<div>
     <% Response.Write(get.SomeString()); %>
</div>
```

Obviously this works fine, but there definitely seems like there should be a shorthand for this.

Comment: Define "shorthand". Thats pretty short

Comment: If you like short syntax consider switching to ASP.Net MVC from WebForms with Razor syntax - 1 character as in `<div>@get.SomeString()</div>` is as short as it could get short of magic...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for `<%: get.SomeString() %>`

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you very much.

Anyone looking in future, it is of course

    <%: get.SomeString() %> 

and make sure you have no ';'

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the semicolon, that tripped me up for a while.

Answer (score 4):

The basic syntax is documented on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6xeyd4z(v=vs.100).aspx):

> Code render blocks define inline code or inline expressions that execute when the page is rendered. There are two styles of code render blocks: inline code and inline expressions. Use inline code to define self-contained lines or blocks of code. **Use inline expressions as a shortcut for calling the [`Write`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.write(v=vs.100).aspx) method.**
>
> ```
> <% inline code %>
> <%=inline expression %>
> ```

In your case, that would look like:

```
<div>
   <%= get.SomeString() %>
</div>
```

Alternatively, while not noted in the MSDN documentation (but mentioned in the comments), in newer versions of ASP.NET, you can also use `<%: … %>` syntax to automatically escape any HTML in before writing it to the output. As [Scott Guthrie explains](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2), this is an important step in guarding against certain forms of attacks. Which form you should choose will depend on your exact use case.